# Rubycas-server can not run on ruby 1.9.2

Tags: yaml, ruby-1.9.2, rubycas

Tried to solve the problem particularly with rubycas-server which is based on sinatara

Getting this error when running rubycas-server

rubycas-server/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:148:in `parse': couldn't parse YAML at line 167 column 2 (Psych::SyntaxError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:148:in`parse_stream'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:119:in `parse'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:106:in`load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rubycas-server-1.0.1/lib/casserver/server.rb:134:in `load_config_file'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rubycas-server-1.0.1/lib/casserver/server.rb:279:in`block in '
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1273:in `configure'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rubycas-server-1.0.1/lib/casserver/server.rb:278:in`'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rubycas-server-1.0.1/lib/casserver/server.rb:12:in `<module:CASServer>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rubycas-server-1.0.1/lib/casserver/server.rb:11:in`'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rubycas-server-1.0.1/lib/casserver.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rubycas-server-1.0.1/bin/rubycas-server:30:in`'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rubycas-server:19:in `load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rubycas-server:19:in`'

I found this solution:

YAML::ENGINE.yamler= 'syck'

But this also dosent work, if someone already tried this thing and found the solution please let me know

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, my /etc/rubycas-server/config.yml had no spaces between some hashes, one i did that and validated my yaml, all works...